# git pull changes automatically from a remote repository

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project on a remote repository `A` which I don't have an access to push to. I had to make a copy of the project in a my own remote repository `B` so that I can work on the project. The main contributors to the project keep adding and changing in the project and they push their changes to the repository `A`. My question what is the best way to keep pulling their changes automatically into my remote repository `B` without making any conflicts?

Comment: Keeping running `git pull`? *without making any conflicts* Well you can't if your code conflicts with theirs then you need to resolve them. Typically if you don't have access to push to the repo you would [fork it](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/). Really though how you manage all this is highly variable. I'm guessing this is some kind of open source repo that you intend to contribute to? If so they should have guidance on how they want you to do this.

Comment: Right now you say you have your own **remote** repo....are you sure because this would be highly unusual and ill advised...if your cloning the repo, you have a local repo, not a remote repo

Comment: @Liam to make thing clear, the copy of the project is on my own remote repository. If I keep running `git pull` I will pull from my own repo.

Comment: why? o_O basically, don't do this. [Fork it](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/), that's what [forks are for](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200663/why-do-people-fork-repositories-on-github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you usually want to do. Git is distributed source control management system. It is meant to be used even when you have no connection to your remote (working on a train, on a plane, ...).

So there is absolutely no reason why you want to keep pulling changes.

To answer you question, you must understand that `git pull` is in fact two commands in one `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, this mean you cannot do `git pull` on a branch you are working on because your working copy is dirty and you might have conflicts.

However you can do `git fetch` to see if somebody has made some changes on the remote. If its the case, Git will kindly remind you this `Your branch is currently ahead of 1 commit...`.